# Wordpress navigation Menu issue

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'm having a problem with the second tier of my navigation showing up when I hover over the products button. You can see the problem here. http://www.americancarpgear.com

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Change line 37 of index.js from:

```
$(this).find('ul').stop(false, true).fadeIn(200);
```

to:

```
$(this).find('ul:first').stop(false, true).fadeIn(200);
```

There are multiple ul's within the Product drop down, so all children are being shown on hover.  Instead, you should only show the first child ul on hover.

Comment: WOW! You just saved me a lot of time, thanks a lot. You're awesome!